# Linux - Starting process at a specific priority

Tags: linux, shell

On Linux, how can I start a process from the terminal at a specific priority value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command `nice`:

```
nice -n 15 <command> <argument1> <argument2> …
```

for example:

```
nice -n 15 sh -c 'while true; do true; done'
```

Comment: is 'date' name of the executable?

Comment: What is the effect of on -p.. ?

Comment: I mean if I start a process from a shell script as: on -p [prio_value] bin

Comment: @Iceman If you mean `nice -n [nice value] command`, not `-p`, then the lower the nice value, the higher the priority of the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `renice` or `nice` (look them up) to reduce the priority. To increase you need to be `root`.